# I want to use custom payment method in prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, payment

I am using prestashop for my online shop. I want to use custom payment option. feature would be similar like cash on delivery. what should i do.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer. 
I just duplicate a module and it just work. Thanks to all.